# How to improve sql script performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following script is very slow when its run.

I have no idea how to improve the performance of the script.
Even with a view takes more than quite a lot minutes.
Any idea please share to me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        ( id )
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    ct.id AS id
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct
                    LEFT JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Customer_ids] hnci ON ct.id = hnci.contact_id
          WHERE     hnci.customer_id IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                            ( [Customer_ID] )
                    FROM    [Transactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header]
                    WHERE   actual_transaction_date > '20120218' )
          UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT
                    contact_id AS id
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[Restaurant_Attendance]
          WHERE     ( created > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000'
                      OR modified > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000'
                    )
                    AND ( [Fifth_Floor_London] = 1
                          OR [Fourth_Floor_Leeds] = 1
                          OR [Second_Floor_Bristol] = 1
                        )
          UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT
                    ( ct.id )
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct
                    INNER JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Wifinity_Devices] wfd ON ct.wifinity_uniqueID = wfd.[CustomerUniqueID]
                                                              AND startconnection > '2012-02-17'
          UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT
                    comdt.id AS id
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[Complete_dataset] comdt
                    LEFT JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Aggregate_Spend_Counts] agsc ON comdt.id = agsc.contact_id
          WHERE     agsc.contact_id IS NULL
                    AND ( opt_out_Mail <> 1
                          OR opt_out_email <> 1
                          OR opt_out_SMS <> 1
                          OR opt_out_Mail IS NULL
                          OR opt_out_email IS NULL
                          OR opt_out_SMS IS NULL
                        )
                    AND ( address_1 IS NOT NULL
                          OR email IS NOT NULL
                          OR mobile IS NOT NULL
                        )
          UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT
                    ( contact_id ) AS id
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[VIP_Card_Holders]
          WHERE     VIP_Card_number IS NOT NULL
        ) AS tbl
```

Comment: first of all avoid subquery if possible then use index! anyway you are executing 5 select. try one at time to see wich one is slow. use the estimate execution plan to see where your query can be optimized

Comment: I do have index keys. If the script above can be made faster, it would be great.  so far, the script gives really poor performance.

Comment: You don't need to to DISTINCT when UNION, all duplicates are already removed.

Comment: @Jarth do you mean to 'distinct' on each sub queries or 'distinct' on very first top one.

Comment: @coder do you have the RIGTH index for any foreignkey? try one select at time to see wich one is slow. if you want help provide a sqlfiddle. no one can help you without some data and how the table are. LAst thing: if you want people to help you consider to increase your accept ratio http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: select distinct (id) will become select id (union remove all duplicated rows).

Comment: This "I have no idea" sounds really bad. Otherwise, remove all DISTINCT keywords, replace UNIONs with UNION ALL (you get some duplicates, but these can be dealt afterwards, although duplicates may indicate query logic errors), run your query in SSMS and look at actual excution plan - where are bottlenecks, what indexes SSMS suggests etc etc.

Comment: First, you've got a lot of `UNION`s and `OR`s, which work fine, but generally do not optimize very well, they just turn into a bunch of separate `SELECT`s that then get merged together.  Given that, the prior suggestion of trying them one at a time isn't a bad idea.  Beyond that advice, it's just guessing unless you provide us with the Query Plan from Management Studio.  The Actual is preferred, but the Estimated is usable.

Comment: How long does it take, and how long would you like it to take?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this, temptable should help you:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Temp1

    --Low perfomance because of using "WHERE  hnci.customer_id IN ( .... ) " - loop join must be
    --and this "where" condition will apply to two tables after left join, 
    --so result will be same as with two inner joints but with bad perfomance

    --SELECT DISTINCT
    --        ct.id AS id
    --INTO    #temp1
    --FROM    [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct
    --        LEFT JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Customer_ids] hnci ON ct.id = hnci.contact_id
    --WHERE   hnci.customer_id IN (
    --        SELECT DISTINCT
    --                ( [Customer_ID] )
    --        FROM    [Transactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header]
    --        WHERE   actual_transaction_date > '20120218' )    
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --this will give the same result but with better perfomance then previouse one
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT DISTINCT
            ct.id AS id
    INTO    #temp1
    FROM    [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct
            JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Customer_ids] hnci ON ct.id = hnci.contact_id
            JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            ( [Customer_ID] )
                   FROM     [Transactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header]
                   WHERE    actual_transaction_date > '20120218'
                 ) T ON hnci.customer_id = T.[Customer_ID]
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------              
    INSERT  INTO #temp1
            ( id
            )
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    contact_id AS id
            FROM    [Customer].[dbo].[Restaurant_Attendance]
            WHERE   ( created > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000'
                      OR modified > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000'
                    )
                    AND ( [Fifth_Floor_London] = 1
                          OR [Fourth_Floor_Leeds] = 1
                          OR [Second_Floor_Bristol] = 1
                        )
    INSERT  INTO #temp1
            ( id
            )
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    ( ct.id )
            FROM    [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct
                    INNER JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Wifinity_Devices] wfd ON ct.wifinity_uniqueID = wfd.[CustomerUniqueID]
                                                                  AND startconnection > '2012-02-17'
    INSERT  INTO #temp1
            ( id
            )
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    comdt.id AS id
            FROM    [Customer].[dbo].[Complete_dataset] comdt
                    LEFT JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Aggregate_Spend_Counts] agsc ON comdt.id = agsc.contact_id
            WHERE   agsc.contact_id IS NULL
                    AND ( opt_out_Mail <> 1
                          OR opt_out_email <> 1
                          OR opt_out_SMS <> 1
                          OR opt_out_Mail IS NULL
                          OR opt_out_email IS NULL
                          OR opt_out_SMS IS NULL
                        )
                    AND ( address_1 IS NOT NULL
                          OR email IS NOT NULL
                          OR mobile IS NOT NULL
                        )
    INSERT  INTO #temp1
            ( id
            )
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    ( contact_id ) AS id
            FROM    [Customer].[dbo].[VIP_Card_Holders]
            WHERE   VIP_Card_number IS NOT NULL

    SELECT DISTINCT
            id
    FROM    #temp1 AS T
```

Comment: This will produce duplicates.  Nothing to stop the additional inserts from inserting an existing value.

Comment: @blam I'm not agree with you, final output used distinct

Comment: OK,  agree.  That final distinct will eliminate the duplicates inserted.  Still don't agree that it would be faster than a set of unions that does this on the fly in memory.

Comment: The use of `IN` hasn't been a general performance problem since the SQL optimizer was rewritten for SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, where to start...

```
--this distinct does nothing.  Union is already distinct
--SELECT DISTINCT
--        ( id )
--FROM    ( 
SELECT DISTINCT [Customer_ID] as ID
          FROM     [Transactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header] 
               where actual_transaction_date > '20120218' )
          UNION
          SELECT 
                    contact_id AS id
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[Restaurant_Attendance]
-- not sure that you are getting the date range you want.  Should these be >= 
-- if you want everything that occurred on the 18th or after you want >= '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000'
-- if you want everything that occurred on the 19th or after you want >= '2012-02-19 00:00:00.000'
-- the way you have it now, you will get everything on the 18th unless it happened exactly at midnight
          WHERE     ( created > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000'
                      OR modified > '2012-02-18 00:00:00.000'
                    )
                    AND ( [Fifth_Floor_London] = 1
                          OR [Fourth_Floor_Leeds] = 1
                          OR [Second_Floor_Bristol] = 1
                        )
-- all of this does nothing because we already have every id in the contact table from the first query
--          UNION
--          SELECT 
--                    ( ct.id )
--          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct
--                    INNER JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Wifinity_Devices] wfd ON ct.wifinity_uniqueID = wfd.[CustomerUniqueID]
--                                                             AND startconnection > '2012-02-17'
          UNION
-- cleaned this up with isnull function and coalesce
          SELECT 
                    comdt.id AS id
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[Complete_dataset] comdt
                    LEFT JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Aggregate_Spend_Counts] agsc ON comdt.id = agsc.contact_id
          WHERE     agsc.contact_id IS NULL
                    AND ( isnull(opt_out_Mail,0) <> 1
                          OR isnull(opt_out_email,0) <> 1
                          OR isnull(opt_out_SMS,0) <> 1
                        )
                    AND coalesce(address_1 , email, mobile) IS NOT NULL
          UNION
          SELECT 
                    ( contact_id ) AS id
          FROM      [Customer].[dbo].[VIP_Card_Holders]
          WHERE     VIP_Card_number IS NOT NULL
--        ) AS tbl
```

Comment: You can also remove all the `DISTINCT`. The result will be the same.

Comment: Your edit in the 1st part of the `UNION` is not right. The `IN (...)` will remove rows form the result.

Comment: @ypercube, good catch.  I misread it the first time.  Removed the comment and put the code back in.  Going to edit it further to improve that query

Comment: @coder I improved the query a little bit more after reading ypercube's comments and corrections

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment optimize one at a time.  See which one takes the longest and focus on that one.

union will remove duplicates so you don't need the distinct on the individual queries

On you first I would try this:

The left join is killed by the WHERE hnci.customer_id IN so you might as well have a join.

The sub-query is not efficient as cannot use an index on the IN.
The query optimizer does not know what in ( select ..  ) will return so it cannot optimize use of indexes.

```
SELECT ct.id AS id
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Contact] ct
  JOIN [Customer].[dbo].[Customer_ids] hnci 
    ON ct.id = hnci.contact_id
  JOIN [Transactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header] th 
    on hnci.customer_id = th.[Customer_ID] 
   and th.actual_transaction_date > '20120218'
```

On that second join the query optimizer has the opportunity of which condition to apply first.  Let say [Customer].[dbo].[Customer_ids].[customer_id] and [Transactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header] each have indexes.  The query optimizer has the option to apply that before [Transactions].[dbo].[Transaction_Header].[actual_transaction_date]. 
If [actual_transaction_date] is not indexed then for sure it would do the other ID join first.

With your in ( select ... ) the query optimizer has no option but to apply the actual_transaction_date > '20120218' first.  OK some times query optimizer is smart enough to use an index inside the in outside the in but why make it hard for the query optimizer.  I have found the query optimizer make better decisions if you make the decisions easier.

A join on a sub-query has the same problem.  You take options away from the query optimizer.  Give the query optimizer room to breathe.

Comment: @Vasily What, your answer is use a temp?  I don't even agree with that point.  I don't recommend a #temp for this.  I post an improvement to one query - you repeat the same queries.

Comment: my answer recommend use temp table and replace where condition with join

Comment: @Blam could you please tell me why shouldn't use #temp ? and why is left join is killed by the where caluse?

Comment: @Vasily Yes and that is NOT my answer so I am not repeating your point.

Comment: hnci.customer_id IN kill the left join.  You will only get values in hnci.  How would writing values to temp just to select the values but faster than just selecting the values?

Comment: @Vasily so you used a join - you are still using a subquery - a subquery loses access to an index (if available)

Comment: @blam yes but distinct will remove duplicates, so it also need to be taken into account

Comment: @Vasily No is does not need to be taken into account there.  Select DISTINCT on the overall query will address that.

Comment: @blam Union not used in my post as you can see

Comment: @Vasily I can see your post.   SELECT DISTINCT ct.id AS id at the top of your query will return distinct value without the distinct in the join sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Where exists is generally faster than in as well.

Or conditions are generally slower as well, use more union statements instead. 
 And learn to use left joins correctly. If you have a where condition (other than where id is null) on the table on teh right side of a left join, it will convert to an inner join. If this is not what you want, then your code is currently giving you an incorrect result set.

See http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN for an explanation of how to fix.

Comment: ^^Comment and not an answer.

Comment: really because when I made that comment this was the entirety of your post "Where exists is generally faster than in as well."

Comment: This bickering is [exactly why FGITW should be outlawed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history). Of course Zane's comment is not accurate *now* but it was accurate for the first revision you posted. And now everyone looks like jerks because Stack Overflow hides the evolution of the answer.

Comment: ANd that was an answer too. It is one factor causing the slowness.

Comment: @HLGEM except in modern versions of SQL Server that's actually not true anymore - SQL Server has gotten pretty smart about optimizing IN as if it were written with EXISTS. And we may disagree about how much substance an answer has to have to actually be an answer. I leave much more complex comments than that.

Comment: First off. If you think in a query with about 15 distincts that the only thing slowing it down is `IN` then you might not be looking at the problem correctly. Second if you do believe changing the `IN` to exists will make the query so much faster how about a generic example of how to do them or at least a link to an MSDN article or something.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that has nothing to do with it, my orginal opost was a perfectly fine answer on it's own. And I don't think it shoudl be outlawed, it is not aboout being first but sometimes it is about getting something important out there while considering the rest or researching something.  Sometimes you read someone else's answer after you post and realize you have missed part of the problem and then add information.  But if you think I am a point hog then go ahead and down vote me.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's worth a down vote. I'm suggesting that (a) that one sentence could just as easily have been a comment and (b) your first comment to Zane was unwarranted.

Comment: The distincts were already mentioned that is why I did not bring them up. If the OP can't look up teh syntax of exists on his own then no link is going to help.

Comment: I completely disagree. This is a small piece of advice perfect for the comment section.